# i have simple firebase code error in the new xcode update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, error-handling, firebase-authentication

this method was writing with swift 3 in swift 4 I get error and I don't know where is the error

```
var CURRENT_USER: User? {
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            return currentUser
        }
        return nil
    }
```

[image: chick this]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator". That also allows you to then search for the error message. I'm relatively certain this problem has been addressed before.

Comment: and don't say i'm certain give me a link

Comment: Is it possible you have some other `User` class defined somewhere other than Firebase?

Comment: yes but this is structural in swift 3 there is no error

Comment: Yes, there's an error. You posted it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The error might have something to do with the optional type since it states that:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'User' to return type 'User?'

A good place to start would be to return an optional value by changing your code to

```
var CURRENT_USER: User? {
    return Auth.auth().currentUser
}
```

Comment: This isn't right. You can return a non-optional value in a function that has an optional return type. It's the other way around that isn't allowed.

Comment: Yeah it used to work in Swift 3. However, not sure about Swift 4. Besides, that's what the error suggests so it seems like a good place to start

Comment: Certainly the code in this answer is the better way to write the method but the explanation just isn't correct, even in Swift 4. Unless there's something I'm missing with the Firebase `User` class (I've never used Firebase).

Comment: Cannot convert return expression of type 'User?' to return type 'User?'

Comment: @rmaddy Makes sense. I haven't used firebase either. Good catch anyway. I'll update the answer

Comment: @mazenqp Make sure that `Auth.auth().currentUser` returns the same `User` model as the one used to define the variable type `var CURRENT_USER: User?`